# QComboBox: same words with different cases are seen as duplicates

Tags: python, qt, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox and say I type the word "info" in the box, followed by "INFO".
Why doesn't it remember both as 2 distinct words and instead convert "INFO" to "info"?

How can I go about solving this issue so that both words would end up in the list. Also the back-end is in python.

Note: I would prefer a solution without setDuplicatesEnabled.
I read the documentation and searched the web but with no luck and I cannot figure this one out. Most answers on SO were outdated(5+ years )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way - to use `setAutoCompletion(false)` on your `QComboBox`.

Comment: I tried that exact code and it didn't work, however you pointer me on the right track and looked into the QCompleter class and after tweaking that I got it to work.`completer = QCompleter()
        completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        self.findTextBox.setCompleter(completer)`